# process 10 lines of the sample data at a time

Tags: bash, file, loops

I would like to make a loop that will take **10 lines** of my input file and output it to an output file. And continue to add lines to the output file not over writing it.

This is a sample data:

```
FilePath    Filename    Probability ClassifierID    HectorFileType  LibmagicFileType

/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 01d0cd964020a1f498c601f9801742c1    19  S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document

/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 0299a1771587043b232f760cbedbb5b7    0   S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
```

I then use this to count each unique file and show how many of each file there is with:

```
cut -f 4 input.txt|sort| uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}' | sed 1d
```

So ultimately I just need help making a loop that can run that line of bash and output 10 lines of data at a time to an output file

Comment: Just to be clear, that's not a line of bash. It's a shell script that executes a lot of external commands.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking – do you want to process 10 lines from your sample data at a time, or do you want to buffer 10 lines of the pipeline at a time and only write to a file when the buffer has 10 lines in it?

Comment: thanks for the correction, I would like to process 10 lines of the sample data at a time

Comment: `split -l 10 infile`, then process each splitfile individually.

Comment: It seems you want to eliminate the header lines, which occurs at line 1, 11, 21, ... Then, do some processing, is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, for every block of 10 lines, you are trying to:

1. Skip the headers, the first line of the block
2. count how many times field #4 (ClassifierID) occurs and output the field, plus the count.

Here is an AWK script which will do it:

```
FNR % 10 != 1 {
    ++count[$4]
}

FNR % 10 == 0 {
    for (i in count) {
        print i, count[i]
        delete count[i]
    }
}
```

## Discussion

- The `FNR % 10 != 1` block processes every line, but lines 1, 11, 21, ... AKA the lines you want to skip. This block keeps a count of field $4
- The `FNR % 10 == 0` block prints out a summary for that block and resets (via delete) the count
- My script does not sort the fields, so the order might be different.
- If you want to tally for the whole file, not just block of 10s, then replace `FNR % 10 == 0` with `END`.

Comment: I get these errors when I try to run it:awk 2script.awk
awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token

Comment: Have you tried `awk -f 2script.awk`? Don't forget the `-f` flag.