# Process portion of file -bash

Tags: bash, loops

before processing data:

```
FilePath    Filename    Probability ClassifierID    HectorFileType  LibmagicFileType
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 01d0cd964020a1f498c601f9801742c1    19  S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 0299a1771587043b232f760cbedbb5b7    0   S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 02a3f29050abd76f8d5dbe5972dff932
```

after running the code below (first column is the classifier and next to it is the number of files):

```
S036GDLv02 1
S040PDFv02 218
S043GUIv02 11
S046CONv02 1
```

I would like to specify the lines of code that I want this to run through:

```
for i in input.txt;

do cut -f 4 input.txt|sort| uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}' | sed 1d >> output.txt; done
```

I want to create a script where I could tell it to run that code through 10 lines for example and have it output it to a file `output.txt`. is that possible to do and what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Are you asking about `sed -n`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335644/process-10-lines-of-the-sample-data-at-a-time ?

Comment: Yes, a duplicate, thus a downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to know what you mean when you say "through ten lines". Do you want to count up only the entries from 10 lines of input.txt, or return the top ten entries.

This will return the top ten entries from a file, sorted in order of abundance.

```
# function to return the ten most common items in a file
# usage: topten input.txt  >> output.txt
topten(){
   cut -f 4 $@ | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2, $1}' | head -10
}
```

To specify how many entries to return:

```
# function to return the N most common items in a file
# usage: topN input.txt 20 >> output.txt
topN(){
   cut -f 4 $1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2, $1}' | head -$2
}
```

Comment: head -10 worked, thanks. Is it possible to say like "echo 20" and then have the command switch to "head -20'?

Comment: you can use `$1` for the file name and $2 for the `head` command and then call it with two arguments. I'll edit to add that example.